# Audio doesn't play right after object.instantiate (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a little game with a gameobject called "bomb". I've coded a script that makes it so whenever you tap or click on the screen, the bomb gameobject gets cloned (using instantiate). Well, on my bomb gameobject I have attached a new script component with  `FindObjectOfType().Play("name")` inside. My bomb is supposed to make a boom sound when colliding with something, so a trigger and that line of code above do that exact thing.

And here comes the problem: When I throw multiple bombs (because my game includes throwing as well) the boom sound plays flawlessly, until another bomb explodes and the boom sound goes all the way to the start and plays again.

The thing is I don't want the same sound to stop, go to the start, and then play again, I want multiple sounds that play independently of each other, so when another bomb explodes, the currently exploding bomb's sound doesn't play again, it should continue playing and another sound to be created for the other bomb explosion.

How can I achieve this?

Here you have a link to a video in which you can hear how bad the explosions sound https://youtu.be/JdIrcgfkVHI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell you are over complicating it when there isn't a need too, Just attach an AudioSource with the bomb clip to the bomb prefab with it set to PlayOnWake.

As for why you're having this issue I think it maybe due to how an AudioSource can only be making one sound at a time so cannot do explosion sounds for 2 bombs at the same time.

**EDIT** Update after comment

You can change if from PlayOnWake to be triggered when hit by the Player using its tag like in this example.

```
public class BombDemo : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AudioSource _soundEffect;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _soundEffect = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            _soundEffect.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

This script when attached to a GameObject with an Audiosource will play it when it is triggered by the Player Object colliding with it.

Keeping this logic on the bomb it self is a lot easier to maintain aswell rather than trying to do it all from the Player side, also if you do need to access the `PlayerController` (or whatever you called it) you can then do so while playing the sound effect using..

`PlayerController playerController = other.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>()`

..for example

Comment: Actually no. If I attach an Audio Source to my bomb that plays on wake, it means that whenever a new bomb will spawn it will play the sound, which I don't want it to do. I want the bomb to only play that sound when it collides with something. And I think my code doesn't attach a new audio source on the bomb duplicates as well, I think it only does it on the original which may explain why it doesn't play 2 sounds at a time. And I suggest you watch the video from the link if you didn't yet.